# Why doesn't LoadFromStream show anything after TIdHTTP.Get?

Tags: delphi, indy

I just began having problems with Indy. For some weird reason, even this very basic procedure doesn't work:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ID: TIdHTTP;
    ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ID:=TIdHTTP.Create();
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;

  ID.HandleRedirects:=true;

  ID.Get('http://www.google.com',ms);
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(ms);
end;
```

Nothing gets added to the Memo1. SizeOf(ms) returns 4.

I even reinstalled Indy, still nothing. My project definitely worked before, but doesn't download anything from any page now. I wonder, what is the problem?

Comment: This is not your actual code, as `TIdHTTP.Create()` won't even compile. If you're having trouble with code, post the actual code, not something you made up that's close to it.

Comment: @ ken I test this code and it work !! and the ms.Position:=0; solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. It has an overridden constructor that accepts no parameters, all the way back at `TIdInitializerComponent`. Glad your problem was solved.

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should mark the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try calling

```
MS.Position := 0;
```

before

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(ms);
```

also, the size of the stream can be found out by invoking the "Size" property like so

```
ShowMessage('size of stream = ' + IntToStr(ms.size) + ' bytes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd, that code should work, assuming similar code worked before.

Sorry, but I **have** to ask:

1. Have you confirmed that accessing that very same URL from that very same machine under that very same user account works from within a browser? Try both a third party browser as well as IE. Can't recall offhand whether Indy uses WinHTTP but it's possible, and a problem affecting WinHTTP such as some piece of malicious software or a BHO will affect IE but won't affect, for example, Firefox, Chrome or Opera.
2. Have you tried turning off your antivirus system and/or your firewall (should you use any non-builtin firewall)? Many antivirus packages include Winsock LSPs or NDIS interceptors for realtime network traffic scanning and might interfere.
3. Finally, failing all that, can you try to fetch that very same URL using a Windows port of [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or [cURL](http://www.gknw.de/mirror/curl/win32/), just to see if other non-browser HTTP clients exhibit issues as well?

Comment: Code definitely doesn't work - LoadFromStream starts at current position.

Comment: Problem was in the MemoryStream.Position. I have one project working already, but I'd simply overseen this part of the code.